# Position divs in corners of an image

Tags: html, css

I am trying to position "BRAND" in the top right corner, and "CATEGORY" in the bottom right corner, of an image.

I am close.

But how do I make it fit exactly inside the image and in the corners top right and bottom right?

```css
.category {
  font-size: 10px;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-style: bold;
  text-align: center;
  color: #777;
  margin-left: 15px;
  outline: 1px solid #fff;
  padding: 2px 20px 2px 8px;
  background-color: yellow;
  opacity: 0.9;
  z-index: 3;
  display: block;
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  opacity: 0.7;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  min-height: 0;
}
.brand {
  font-size: 10px;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-style: bold;
  text-align: center;
  color: #777;
  margin-left: 15px;
  outline: 1px solid #fff;
  padding: 2px 20px 2px 8px;
  background-color: #fff;
  opacity: 0.9;
  z-index: 3;
  display: block;
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  opacity: 0.7;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  min-height: 0;
}
.image {
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  display: block;
  padding: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="image">
  <a href="#" target="_blank">
    <img alt="img" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/400">
  </a>

  <div class="brand">
    Brand</div>

  <div class="category">
    Category
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make the container (`div.image`) a relatively-positioned bounding box, which will allow you to absolutely position the children within its borders:

```css
.image {
  position: relative;           /* 1 */
  display: inline-block;        /* 2 */  
}
.brand {
  position: absolute;           /* 3 */
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.category {
  position: absolute;           /* 3 */
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="image">
  <a href="#" target="_blank">
    <img alt="img" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/400">
  </a>
  <div class="brand">Brand</div>
  <div class="category">Category</div>
</div>
```

Notes:

1. [Establish nearest positioned ancestor for absolute positioning.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#Absolute_positioning)
2. Width of container is width of in-flow content
3. Use absolute positioning with offset properties (`top`, `bottom`, `left`, `right`) to move child elements within container