# Position DIVs in top right of image and in top bottom another div

Tags: html, css

I try to position two DIVs inside an image... the DIV called "brand car" should be in the exact top right corner of the image. And the second DIV called "seller car" should be in right bottom corner of the image. Is that possible (I have the entire DIV structure as displayed in the code which I have to absolutely keep)?

```css
.image-video-linkmas img {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0px;
  }
  
.brandmas {
    font-size: 10px;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-style: bold;
    text-align: center;
    color: #777;
    margin-left: 15px;
    outline: 1px solid #fff;
    padding: 2px 20px 2px 8px;
    background-color: red;
    opacity: 0.9;
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0.7;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    min-height: 0;
  }

.categorymas { 
 font-size: 10px;
 font-weight: 700;
 font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
 font-style: bold;
 text-align: center;
 color: #777;
 margin-left: 15px;
 /*outline: 1px solid #fff;*/
 padding: 2px 20px 2px 8px;
 background-color: yellow;
 position: absolute;
 opacity: 0.7;
 bottom: 0;
 right: 0;
 /*min-height: 0;*/
  }
```

```html
<div class="container">
        <div class="rows">
            <div id="articleslist">
                <div class="article">
                    <article class="item">
                        <div class="item_inner">
                            <div class="image-video-linkmas">
                                <a href="#" target=
                                "_blank"><img alt="#" src=
                                "http://lorempixel.com/400/400"></a>
                                <div class="brandmas">
                                    BRAND CAR
                                </div>
                                <div class="categorymas">
                                   SELLER CAR
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </article>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Something like this https://jsfiddle.net/0vLmt3L5/10/

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39134173/3597276

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were so close man!

You may be asking yourself, **what is going on?**

> What is happening is the absolutely positioned elements are
>   positioning themselves in relation to the body element instead of
>   their direct parent.

Remember that when you use `position: absolute;` on child elements, the parent one should have `position: relative;`else they will always position in relation to the body element.

---

[**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/rickyruizm/19jnp4zr/)

---

```css
.image-video-linkmas {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
.image-video-linkmas img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 0px;
}
.brandmas {
  font-size: 10px;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-style: bold;
  text-align: center;
  color: #777;
  margin-left: 15px;
  outline: 1px solid #fff;
  padding: 2px 20px 2px 8px;
  background-color: red;
  opacity: 0.9;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0.7;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  min-height: 0;
}
.categorymas {
  font-size: 10px;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-style: bold;
  text-align: center;
  color: #777;
  margin-left: 15px;
  /*outline: 1px solid #fff;*/
  padding: 2px 20px 2px 8px;
  background-color: yellow;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0.7;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  /*min-height: 0;*/
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="rows">
    <div id="articleslist">
      <div class="article">
        <article class="item">
          <div class="item_inner">
            <div class="image-video-linkmas">
              <a href="#" target="_blank">
                <img alt="#" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/400">
              </a>
              <div class="brandmas">
                BRAND CAR
              </div>
              <div class="categorymas">
                SELLER CAR
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </article>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: A la orden pa'l desorden! Read [**this**](https://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/) it may help you for further info. Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the `relative` position to the wrapping (parent) `div` not the image itself, see fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/0vLmt3L5/10/

```
.image-video-linkmas {
    max-width: 400px;
    max-height: 400px;
    margin: 0;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0px;
  }
 .image-video-linkmas img{    
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
 } 
.brandmas {
    font-size: 10px;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-style: bold;
    text-align: center;
    color: #777;
    margin-left: 15px;
    outline: 1px solid #fff;
    padding: 2px 20px 2px 8px;
    background-color: red;
    opacity: 0.9;
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0.7;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    min-height: 0;
  }

.categorymas { 
    font-size: 10px;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-style: bold;
    text-align: center;
    color: #777;
    margin-left: 15px;
    /*outline: 1px solid #fff;*/
    padding: 2px 20px 2px 8px;
    background-color: yellow;
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0.7;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    /*min-height: 0;*/
  }
```

Comment: @raulbaros make sure to upvote the other answers that are the same as mine, we all answered at the same time with the same answer.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it.
Add the divs inside the `a` element and make it `position: relative` and `display: inline-block`

```css
.image-video-linkmas a {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  height: 400px;
}
.image-video-linkmas img {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0px;
  }
  
.brandmas {
    font-size: 10px;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-style: bold;
    text-align: center;
    color: #777;
    margin-left: 15px;
    outline: 1px solid #fff;
    padding: 2px 20px 2px 8px;
    background-color: red;
    opacity: 0.9;
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0.7;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    min-height: 0;
  }

.categorymas { 
 font-size: 10px;
 font-weight: 700;
 font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
 font-style: bold;
 text-align: center;
 color: #777;
 margin-left: 15px;
 /*outline: 1px solid #fff;*/
 padding: 2px 20px 2px 8px;
 background-color: yellow;
 position: absolute;
 opacity: 0.7;
 bottom: 0;
 right: 0;
 /*min-height: 0;*/
  }
```

```html
<div class="container">
        <div class="rows">
            <div id="articleslist">
                <div class="article">
                    <article class="item">
                        <div class="item_inner">
                            <div class="image-video-linkmas">
                                <a href="#" target=
                                "_blank"><img alt="#" src=
                                "http://lorempixel.com/400/400">
                                <div class="brandmas">
                                    BRAND CAR
                                </div>
                                <div class="categorymas">
                                   SELLER CAR
                                </div></a>
                                
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </article>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your style.

```
.item_inner {
  position: absolute;
}
```

Note that this may instead be added to one of these classes instead if you want:

- container
- articleslist
- article
- item

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to hide the picture?
If so,the two DIVs must have `position:absolute;`,adjust top and left of two DIVs.
If not, think about what you want.